# Form robot to submit multiple javascript form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have multiple form named from "form1" to "form5" within a same root url, for example 222.111.111.100/Form/. In the first page, which means

http://222.111.111.100/Form/B.do?a=first

The form in the response http request would be writtin in a general style as following:

```
<form name="form1" action="B.do?a=first" method="post"  > 
<input name="sure" type="checkbox" id="sure" value="" /> 
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="NextStep" /> 
</form>
```

I need to fill the form automatically one by one as the previous form will have impact on the next one. And to be clear, after this form1, the url will trace to:

http://222.111.111.100/Form/B.do?a=second

The problem is when I using `cUrl` to get the content, then javascript dealing with the input checkbox or submit/nextstep button, the `document.forms[0].submit()` for each form does not working. Even if i passed to the second page, it seems that the Global Variable have not been passed to the next page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to solve your problem, i sugest you to learn about Selenium. Selenium allows you to automate browsers, it is mainly used for automating web applications for testing purposes.

Otherwise it would be completely recreate JavaScript calls, but this would not allow use JavaScript itself as apparently you desire.

Selenium: http://www.seleniumhq.org/

Comment: Thank you for your rapid response. The selenium seems to run with a server side and a client side. As in the future, some data will also be automatically filled and posted to the form, so, this proposition will not be easily implementable. While, for a repeatable form submit action, this selenium will be a great tool.

Comment: Actually, you can extend Selenium with many high level languages, so, you can run server & client locally and then wrap the Selenium webdriver with other actions.

Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your situation correctly, but I will say it: Javascript is client side only, so if you change page or reload, the variables available to your js code will get back to their initial value.

So if you have control on the server side, you can make the page `B.do?a=first` return (for example) a json data string which your js may use to fill the next form.